# Where do large logarithms come from? Weinberg, Chapter 18, QFT Volume 2

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

I am having trouble understanding a statement from Weinberg's book. Let me give you a bit of background before I ask about the statement. Weinberg considers the following:

1. Let's take a physical amplitude, a cross-section or other rate parameter, such as decay rate: $\Gamma[E, x, g, m]$ that depends on energy scale (we are not saying how yet); various angles and energy ratios, collectively called x; dimensionless coupling constants of the theory called $g$ (from interactions); various masses collectively called $m$.
   If we just go by pure dimensional analysis and say the dimensions of $\Gamma = [mass]^D$, for example, for scattering cross-section we will have $[mass]^{-2}$, then:
   \begin{align*}
       \Gamma = E^D\Gamma(1, x, g, \frac{m}{E}).
   \end{align*}
2. From dimensional analysis, we might assume that at high energies, $\Gamma$ will have a power law scaling. But when we do the calculation for scattering amplitude etc, what we find is $E^D$ accompanies with powers of $\ln{\frac{E}{m}}$. Obviously, we have $E^D$ to dimensionally agree, but it comes with a problematic factors of $\ln{\frac{E}{m}}$, not just one factor but many depending on loop calculations, so we don't have a simple power law.
3. Now comes the statement, I am not sure I am interpreting correctly: ***Clearly, powers of $\ln(E/m)$ enter as E $\rightarrow \infty$ with fixed mass only if amplitude $\Gamma$ at fixed energy $E$ becomes singular as $m\rightarrow 0$.***  It might be something silly, but please let me know how you interpret this statement.  It's in third paragraph of section 18.1. *I think the statement is just about the nature of logarithm, as in if you have a logarithm of $E/m$ in your $\Gamma$ then your amplitude must also be becoming singular as $m\rightarrow0$.*